# Convert text column to integer

Tags: postgresql

I have a column name males_pop and the data in it is in the text format and the column is also text . But I wanted to convert the data type of the column as well as the data in it to integer.
Like males_pop  12,367,897 to 12367897.
How I can do?

I don't know the query .Please help me

Answer (score 1):

When all of the values are in this format - I believe you will have to replace the `,` first, in order to cast it to an int.

In order to change the column type and use a newly casted value:

```sql
alter table sth 
alter column male_pop type integer USING (REPLACE(male_pop, ',','')::int);
```

https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/mMxeaqC9oKnX1PTmd7MwKc/0

Comment: It's giving an error  ' invalid  input syntax  for type integer

Comment: When I created a new column of type integer and after creating a new column I have copied the data of type char to new column which is int of type.

Comment: As you can see in the fiddle - it is working with the example data you provided. The invalid input error must come from another format, which you have not provided.

Comment: UPDATE  table_name SET males_pop =repalce(males_pop, ', ', ' ')::int; By doing these things its working.  Which is a two step process .I want to know is there any short cut ,like I don't have to create a new column .

Comment: Yes - see my answer above. `alter... using...` . should be the way to go. If this throws an error, there must be a value, which is not processable. Hard to day, without actually seeing all the values involved.